# I need another set of eyes to tell me what's wrong with this pipe and sed

Tags: bash, sed, pipe, rename

Again I am trying to rename some video files, and again I am having problems with my command.  If I could get another set of eyes to look at this and figure out what i'm not seeing I would be grateful.

I have files like this;

```
'DARK Matter S01E03 Episode Three.mp4'

'DARK Matter S01E04 Episode Four.mp4'
```

etc...

I am trying to remove the `" Episode Three", " Episode Four"` etc from the names and I wrote this command, but it's not quite working as expected.

```
for file in *Episode*;do echo "rename \"$file\" "\"$file" | sed 's/ Episode*./.')";done
```

The result of this command is;

```
rename "DARK Matter S01E03 Episode Three.mp4" "DARK Matter S01E03 Episode Three.mp4 | sed 's/ Episode*./.')
rename "DARK Matter S01E04 Episode Four.mp4" "DARK Matter S01E04 Episode Four.mp4 | sed 's/ Episode*./.')
rename "DARK Matter S01E05 Episode Five.mp4" "DARK Matter S01E05 Episode Five.mp4 | sed 's/ Episode*./.')
```

It's not recognizing the pipe to sed and my sed command itself is not written correctly (I know, i'm terrible with regular expressions).
I would appreciate any help you could give.

Comment: Maybe you want `find . -type f -name '*Episode*' -exec bash -c 'echo mv $0 $(sed "s/ Episode[^.]*//" <<< $0)' "{}" \;`?

Comment: `find . -type f -name '*Episode*' -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "$(sed "s/ Episode[^.]*//" <<< $0)"' "{}" \;` actually renames.

Comment: Well, That would work I suppose, but it completely rewrites my original one-liner.
Fortunately I figured out my own solution (thanks to you!)

Comment: Both your pipe operator and your sed command are inside the double quote of the string passed to the `echo` command. Hence, there is no pipe at all in your code.

Comment: BTW, `echo SOMETHING | somecommand` can be more reliabaly be written as `somecommand <<<SOMETHING`. Note that echo does not necessarily output the exactly same sequence of characters which is passed as argument, unless you use `echo -nE SOMETHING`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `regex` and pulling the matching pieces from the `BASH_REMATCH[]` array:

```
regex='(.*) Episode [^.]+(.*)'

for file in *Episode*
do
    if [[ "${file}" =~ $regex ]]
    then
        # typeset -p BASH_REMATCH
        newfile="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        cp "${file}" "${newfile}"
    fi
done
```

**NOTES:**

- the `regex` is defined to pickup anything after the first period (eg, `.mp4`, `.mkv`, `some.other.suffix`)
- uncomment the `typeset -p` command to display the contents of the `BASH_REMATCH[]` array
- replace `cp` with `mv` once the results have been verified

Assuming the following files:

```
$ ls -l DARK*
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 0 Feb 23 20:02 DARK\ Matter\ S01E03\ Episode\ Three.mp4
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 0 Feb 23 20:02 DARK\ Matter\ S01E04\ Episode\ Four.mp4
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 0 Feb 23 20:03 DARK\ Matter\ S01E05\ Episode\ Five.mkv
```

The code results in the following:

```
$ ls -l DARK*
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 0 Feb 23 20:02 DARK\ Matter\ S01E03\ Episode\ Three.mp4
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 0 Feb 23 20:08 DARK\ Matter\ S01E03.mp4
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 0 Feb 23 20:02 DARK\ Matter\ S01E04\ Episode\ Four.mp4
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 0 Feb 23 20:08 DARK\ Matter\ S01E04.mp4
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 0 Feb 23 20:03 DARK\ Matter\ S01E05\ Episode\ Five.mkv
-rw-rw----+ 1 username None 0 Feb 23 20:08 DARK\ Matter\ S01E05.mkv
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself finally;

```
for file in *Episode*;do echo "rename \"$file\" \"$file\"" | sed 's/ Episode[^.]*//2';done
```

rename "DARK Matter S01E03 Episode Three.mp4" "DARK Matter S01E03.mp4"

rename "DARK Matter S01E04 Episode Four.mp4" "DARK Matter S01E04.mp4"

rename "DARK Matter S01E05 Episode Five.mp4" "DARK Matter S01E05.mp4"

Comment: oh, and I changed the 'rename' to 'mv'